# How to add permission READ_PHONE_STATE to Android instrumentation test?

Tags: android

I am new in writing tests on Android Studio. By using UiAutomator to write instrumentation tests, I have done some auto tests. However, when I need to get device IMEI and Service state, which requires permission READ_PHONE_STATE, I always got SecurityException not allowed to perform even I have added permission in Manifest and code.

Checking Android doc I know that permission READ_PHONE_STATE is in Dangerous level so I need to get permission from the user at runtime. But the problem is my test code does not contain Activity. I did research on web for several days, including dig out a possible solution in Stack Overflow, but no luck.

What I have tried includes:

1.Using @Rule

```
@Rule 
public GrantPermissionRule mRuntimePermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
```

2.Using shell command:

```
myDevice.executeShellCommand("pm grant com.mp.rss android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE");
```

3.Using PermissionRequester (I can see permission granted in Logcat but still got SecurityException)

```
PermissionRequester pr = new PermissionRequester();
pr.addPermissions("android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE");
pr.requestPermissions();
```

In logcat: I/GrantPermissionCallable: Permission: android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE is already granted!

4.Try to prompt for asking permission but fails because there is no Activity in my test program.

```
 int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 100;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE )){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    } 
   }
```

Here is my manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mp.rss">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RREAD_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBER"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
</manifest>
```

**Here is my code**

```
 public class rss {
      private static UiDevice myDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
      private static Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
      public static void writeDeviceinfo( ) throws IOException, NullPointerException, UiObjectNotFoundException {
        PermissionRequester pr = new PermissionRequester();
        pr.addPermissions("android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE");
        pr.requestPermissions();
        try {
            TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            writeLog("[PrintInfo] Device service is  = " + tMgr.getServiceState());
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            writeLog("[PrintInfo] Device service is = ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the exception message I got for above 4 methods I have tried**

```
`java.lang.SecurityException: com.mp.rss.test from uid 10181 not allowed to perform OP_READ_PHONE_STATE
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1946)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1914)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1864)
at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getServiceStateForSubscriber(ITelephony.java:5590)
at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getServiceStateForSubscriber(TelephonyManager.java:7576)
at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getServiceState(TelephonyManager.java:7564)
at .....`
```